# JavaCV generate video from images Crashes

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, javacv

I am doing javacv with android since yesterday and getting error while generating video from image (IplImage) using **FFmpegFrameRecorder** or **FrameRecorder** while getting succes in imagefiltering using **cvCvtColor** and **cvCvtColor**.

[image: grayscale]

As shown in picture , **Grayscale** and **flip** filter is done by clicking second Button **(Apply Effect)**.

But when clicking **(Make Video)** it crashes.

Here is my code for making video from image.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/test.mp4";
Log.i("path", path);
FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(path, 256, 256);
try {

    recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4);
    // recorder.setCodecID(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H263);
    recorder.setFormat("mp4");
    recorder.setPixelFormat(avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
    recorder.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        recorder.record(image);
    }
    recorder.stop();
} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**image** is of type IplImage

getting error on **recorder** object creation.

I am using 2 devices

1)Asus zenfone 5

**Stacktrace**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:387)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat.<clinit>(avformat.java:13)
            at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<clinit>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:106)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.makeVideo(MainActivity.java:191)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:180)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:152)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:385)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat.<clinit>(avformat.java:13)
            at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<clinit>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:106)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.makeVideo(MainActivity.java:191)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:180)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:152)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app-lib/com.example.javacvex1-1/libjniavcodec.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:535)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:410)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec.<clinit>(avcodec.java:12)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:385)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat.<clinit>(avformat.java:13)
            at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<clinit>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:106)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.makeVideo(MainActivity.java:191)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:180)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:152)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app-lib/com.example.javacvex1-1/libavcodec.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40
```

2) Htc me tablet

**(Stacktrace)**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.makeVideo(MainActivity.java:191)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:180)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:152)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<clinit>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:106)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.makeVideo(MainActivity.java:191)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:180)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:152)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:385)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat.<clinit>(avformat.java:13)
            at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<clinit>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:106)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.makeVideo(MainActivity.java:191)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:180)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:152)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1936]:    76 could not load needed library 'libavcodec.so' for 'libjniavcodec.so' (find_library[1199]:    76 'libavcodec.so' failed to load previously)
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:535)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:410)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec.<clinit>(avcodec.java:12)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:385)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat.<clinit>(avformat.java:13)
            at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<clinit>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:106)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.makeVideo(MainActivity.java:191)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:180)
            at com.example.javacvex1.MainActivity$asyncImageProcVideo.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:152)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1936]:    76 could not load needed library 'libswresample.so' for 'libavcodec.so' (load_library[1091]: Library 'libswresample.so' not found)
```

At last I am putting my **build.gradle** with **jniLibs** on left side.

[image]

No luck with answers from other questions. Stuck since last 24 hours. :(

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javacv/Q_jxavoWdZE

I finally solved it by adding

```
Loader.load(swresample.class);
```

before creating FFmpegFrameRecorder object.
Thank you.